# swift calls self before super.init

Tags: swift, initialization

Access `self` before `super.init()`call is forbid according to the document.Why use `self.properties` is correct.

```
var myString: String
init(frame: CGFloat) {
    //error:'self' userd before super.init call
    print(self)
    self.myString = "11"
    print(self.myString)

    super.init()
}
```

Why It occurs an error calls `print(self)`，calls `print(self.myString)`is ok?

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is logical context, let's walk through this.

In the line `self.myString = "11"`, you declare what myString is, which is `== "11"`.

Now, you could `print(self.myString)`.

But! You canNOT print self, because SELF was never initialized/declared! You must call SOME kind of initializer, i.e. the parent initializer `(super.init)` and then you declare/instantiate some type of object.

So you may not necessarily know what SELF is, but you can definitely determine what `self.myString` is!